# Trouble getting tableview section /rows to populate with correct count and data. from plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm hitting a bit of a snag in the final days of my project. The issue is, i'm trying to populate my table view with sections read from a user created and editable plist file.

Currently the cells without grouping populate fine. The cells even stack next to each other.
However what i would like to do is create sections for each group (by title)

So section one would all have the title of section one. And section two would do the same.
What i'm getting is all the same titles (cells) in all of the groups.

I've managed to create sections for titles and display those titles in the header.

I think that my issue is how I'm trying to populate the rowsFroSections and cellForRows.

Here are a couple of code snips.

I pull the data from the plist into an array then sort it like this in the viewDidAppear

```
self.accessDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:appDelegate.pathToUserCopyOfPlist];

NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ProjectID" ascending:YES];
[accessDataArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Then I consolidate the the array to remove dupes for the section count and titles like this.

```
mutset = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init ];

if ([accessDataArray count]>1) {

    for (i = 0; i < [accessDataArray count]; i++) {
        [mutset addObject:[[accessDataArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ProjectID"]];
        NSLog(@"mutable count = %d",[mutset count]);

       }
    }

    setToArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithSet:mutset];
    NSLog(@" setarray count = %d",[setToArray count]);

    for (int m = 0; m < [mutset count]; m++) {
      NSLog(@"new array %@",[setToArray objectAtIndex:m]);
    }`
```

Then I access the populated arrays like this. 
I have commented-out a couple of items to maintain app stability.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [setToArray count];


}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 60;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([accessDataArray count]==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else{

        return [[accessDataArray objectAtIndex:section]count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if ([accessDataArray count]==0) {
        return @"";
    }
    else{
        return [setToArray objectAtIndex:section];
    }


}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
 //   int section = indexPath.section; 

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.shadowColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.shadowColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 18.0 ];
    }   
    if ([accessDataArray count]==0) {
        if ([indexPath row]==0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Projects On File"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text= nil;
        }

    }

    if ([accessDataArray count]>0) {

        NSDictionary *dic = [accessDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [dic objectForKey:@"ProjectID"];
        [dic objectForKey:@"Location"];
        [dic objectForKey:@"Hook"];
        [dic objectForKey:@"Date"];

        cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"ProjectID"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(Location %@) (Hook %@)  -%@- "
                                ,[dic objectForKey:@"Location"]
                                ,[dic objectForKey:@"Hook"]
                                ,[dic objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Here is the debug log that the app generates:

```
2011-09-16 12:06:52.318 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 0: Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.320 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 1: Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.321 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 2: Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.322 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 3: New Prop
2011-09-16 12:06:52.324 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 4: New Prop
2011-09-16 12:06:52.326 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 5: Not Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.327 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 6: Not Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.327 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 7: Store
2011-09-16 12:06:52.328 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 8: Store
2011-09-16 12:06:52.328 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 9: Store
2011-09-16 12:06:52.329 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 10: all doors
2011-09-16 12:06:52.332 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 11: all doors
2011-09-16 12:06:52.333 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 1
2011-09-16 12:06:52.333 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 1
2011-09-16 12:06:52.334 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 1
2011-09-16 12:06:52.334 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 2
2011-09-16 12:06:52.334 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 2
2011-09-16 12:06:52.335 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 3
2011-09-16 12:06:52.381 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 3
2011-09-16 12:06:52.382 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 4
2011-09-16 12:06:52.382 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 4
2011-09-16 12:06:52.383 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 4
2011-09-16 12:06:52.383 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 5
2011-09-16 12:06:52.384 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 5
2011-09-16 12:06:52.384 LockPin[617:b303]  setarray count = 5
2011-09-16 12:06:52.386 LockPin[617:b303] new array all doors
2011-09-16 12:06:52.386 LockPin[617:b303] new array New Prop
2011-09-16 12:06:52.387 LockPin[617:b303] new array Not Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.388 LockPin[617:b303] new array Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.388 LockPin[617:b303] new array Store
```

---

Ok, I changed the code, in the original post. She correct amount of section headers and titleFor header is showing. In each section i have the amount of objects that exist in the array (count) in each section. Here is the debug log that the app generates with the current setup. Maybe this will help shed some light.

```
2011-09-16 12:06:52.318 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 0: Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.320 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 1: Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.321 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 2: Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.322 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 3: New Prop
2011-09-16 12:06:52.324 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 4: New Prop
2011-09-16 12:06:52.326 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 5: Not Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.327 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 6: Not Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.327 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 7: Store
2011-09-16 12:06:52.328 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 8: Store
2011-09-16 12:06:52.328 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 9: Store
2011-09-16 12:06:52.329 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 10: all doors
2011-09-16 12:06:52.332 LockPin[617:b303] object at index 11: all doors
2011-09-16 12:06:52.333 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 1
2011-09-16 12:06:52.333 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 1
2011-09-16 12:06:52.334 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 1
2011-09-16 12:06:52.334 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 2
2011-09-16 12:06:52.334 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 2
2011-09-16 12:06:52.335 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 3
2011-09-16 12:06:52.381 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 3
2011-09-16 12:06:52.382 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 4
2011-09-16 12:06:52.382 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 4
2011-09-16 12:06:52.383 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 4
2011-09-16 12:06:52.383 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 5
2011-09-16 12:06:52.384 LockPin[617:b303] mutable count = 5
2011-09-16 12:06:52.384 LockPin[617:b303]  setarray count = 5
2011-09-16 12:06:52.386 LockPin[617:b303] new array all doors
2011-09-16 12:06:52.386 LockPin[617:b303] new array New Prop
2011-09-16 12:06:52.387 LockPin[617:b303] new array Not Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.388 LockPin[617:b303] new array Main
2011-09-16 12:06:52.388 LockPin[617:b303] new array Store
```

Comment: sorry about the formatting on the code not sure why it looks like that

Comment: You return 1 from numberOfSectionsInTable so there's only one section in your table. Then in numberOfRowsInSeciton I would have expected you to use the section parameter to determine how many rows there are but the section parameter is not used in that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're going to uncomment out return 1;//[setToArray count];  which presumably will return the number of "headers" (aka sections) you have, and in the numberOfRowsInSection, you want to return the number of rows for the section that passed into you as a parameter. Make sure you're returning an NSString in your titleForHeaderInSection routine.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code, in the original post. She correct amount of section headers and titleFor header is showing. In each section i have the amount of objects that exist in the array (count) in each section.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of your problem -- is it that the display of your arrays doesn't correspond to the array structure, or that you can't get the array to load into the structure you want?

Comment: Yes, the cells that display don't correspond to the section. What i want is Section 0 title = Main, then only the objects that have title of "Main" would exist in that section. What I'm getting is all objects populate all sections.

Comment: You'll have to do the filtering in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Basically, cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called by the system, and your code provides the system with the proper cell (object).  So you'll get called with an NSIndexPath.  The indexpath.section will tell you which section you have to provide the info for, and the indexpath.row will tell you which row.  So, check your indexpath parameter in cellForRowAtIndexPath and provide the proper information in that cell that you return.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Now only if can punch it out...(translate into code)

Comment: Look at this line in your code:     NSDictionary *dic = [accessDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; -- it looks like it's just accessing it by section.  You need to make it a bit smarter so it selects by section and row.

Comment: Ok so i got the rowForCell fixed with 'if ([accessDataArray count]==0) {
    return 1;
}
else{
   // return 1;//[setToArray count];
    NSString *temp =  [setToArray objectAtIndex:section];
    int i =0;
    for (int r = 0; r < [accessDataArray count]; r++) {
       if ([temp isEqualToString:[[accessDataArray objectAtIndex:r] objectForKey:@"ProjectID"]]) {
            ++i;

        }
    }


    return i;
}'

Comment: You'll probably get better performance and certainly less complexity if you preprocess your array so that it better matches what you want to do.  Here's what I'd do: Make an array which holds other arrays for your rows.  This container array corresponds to your sections.  Then make other arrays for each section for all the rows of that section.  So that you can in cellForRowAtIndex path use something like:  [[myDataArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row]

Comment: For each section, create an array that corresponds to the data for each row in that section, then add that array to an NSMutableArray which corresponds to that section.  If there are no rows, don't add the section, unless you need to show that header, in which case add an empty array.